# Process.env undefined in vite

Tags: javascript, tesseract, vite, nuxtjs3

I trying to use Tesserract.js `https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#documentation` with Vue.js which uses Vite as bundler.

My problem is that I get this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'TESS_ENV')

This error happens inside:

```
module.exports = {
  ...defaultOptions,
  workerPath: (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process.env.TESS_ENV === 'development')
    ? resolveURL(`/dist/worker.dev.js?nocache=${Math.random().toString(36).slice(3)}`)
    : `https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@v${version}/dist/worker.min.js`,
  /*
   * If browser doesn't support WebAssembly,
   * load ASM version instead
   */
  corePath: `https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js-core@v${dependencies['tesseract.js-core'].substring(1)}/tesseract-core.${typeof WebAssembly === 'object' ? 'wasm' : 'asm'}.js`,
};
```

Well, in vite I need to use `import.meta.env.MODE` instead of `process.env.TESS_ENV`

I tried to change the tesseract.js code. I went inside:

node_modules -> tesseract -> src -> worker -> browser -> defaultOptions.js

And changed it to `import.meta.env.MODE` but for some reason the code does not get applied and it still displays me the old error.

How do I make this work?

Comment: [Prefix your variables with `VITE`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files) or they will get ignored.

Answer (score 5):

I got it:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    define: {
      "process.env.TESS_ENV": process.env.ENV,
    },
  },
});
```

I need to defined it, now its not undefined anymore

Comment: This one doesn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73012071/process-env-undefined-in-vite#comment128953263_73012071

Comment: "process.env": { PORT: "3000", } -- try this

Answer (score 3):

Remember to use the correct prefixes for **.env** file used in Vite, Nuxt etc.
ex.:

**Vite .env**

```js
//.env file
VITE_BASE_URL: 'example.com'
```

**Nuxt3 .env**

```js
//.env file
NUXT_BASE_URL: 'example.com'
```

##### OR

define it straight inside defineNuxtConfig

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vite, you might wanna try to use your variables this way: *import.meta.env.VITE_VARIABLE_NAME*.
In your code it will look something like this:

**.env**

```
VITE_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8080
```

**App.js or App.jsx (or any other component)**

```
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const backendUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL;
  console.log(backendUrl);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>.env with Vite</h1>
      <p>{backendUrl}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Remarks**

- There's no need to put variable values between quotes in your .env file
- There's no need to install the dotenv package for this to work
- Variables declared in the .env file should have a name starting with VITE_